# Using set in a C# class

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class:

```
public class Class1
{
    private int pam1;

    public Class1()
    {

    }

    public void ChangePam1(int _NewValue)
    {
        UpdatePam1(_NewValue);
        pam1 = _NewValue;
    }

    public int Pam1
    {
        set { this.pam1 = value; }
        get { return this.pam1; }
    }
}
```

Currently, when I want to change the value of `Pam1`, I do the following:

```
int n = 500;
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
c1.ChangePam1(n);
```

How can I change it using `Set`?

Comment: Are you asking how to set a property?, `c1.Pam1 = 500`

Comment: Not only setting a property, but also doing stuff related to the change, in this case, updating the value in the database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this (It will call the `set`):

```
public class Class1
{
    private int pam1;

    public Class1(){}

    private void ChancePam1(int newValue)
    {
        UpdatePam1(newValue);
        pam1 = newValue;
    }

    public int Pam1
    {
        set { ChancePam1(value); }
        get { return this.pam1; }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
int n = 500;
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
c1.Pam1 = n;
```

Also have look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx).

Comment: That won't update the value in db!

Comment: Setting a property should typically not have such a drastic side effect (updating the DB). If you want that behavior, a method is more appropriate (see [Use properties where appropriate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182181.aspx))

Comment: @enb081 Because this code doesn't do relevant about database updates.

Comment: It's better to make `ChanceParam1` private in order to keep encapsulation.

Comment: If a method is more appropriate, then I should leave it the way it is? But all my objects correspond to DataBase tables, and It is easier to write `c1.Pam1 = n` than `c1.ChangePam1(n);`

Comment: It would be better to have an `UpdateDatabase()` method which updates all the columns for the record - otherwise you'll be roundtripping to the DB on every property update.

Answer (score 6):

Just set your `c1` object's `Pam1` property.

```
c1.Pam1 = n;
```

Or you can use;

```
public int Pam1
{
    set { ChancePam1(value); }
    get { return this.pam1; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to do something else, define it in your code

```
public int Pam1
{
    set { 
         this.pam1 = value; 
         UpdatePam1(value);
         }
    get { return this.pam1; }
}
```

You can work in a `setter` almost like in a normal method.

When in doubt, consider [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Changing your class in following way might be a good idea:

```
public class Class1
{
    private int pam1;

    public Class1()
    {

    }

    public int Pam1
    {
        set { UpdatePam1(_NewValue);this.pam1 = value; }
        get { return this.pam1; }
    }
}
```

... and to work with your property:

```
int n = 500;
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
c1.pam1=n;
```

Answer (score 2):

you just have to call the UpdatePam1(value) in your set

```
public int Pam1
{
    set { UpdatePam1(value);
          pam1 = value; 
        }
    get { return this.pam1; }
}
```

or

```
 public int Pam1
{
    set { ChangePam1(value); }
    get { return this.pam1; }
}
```